# Mainscript executes subscripts in a new terminal window

Tags: bash, terminal, debian, subscript

"Debian 9 64x - LXDE"

I try to create an install script in bash. Lets assume i want to install samba. I call from the mainscript the install script for samba `\folder\samba.sh`. The script samba.sh should get executed in a new terminal window, so i can watch for install errors.

**The script should work like follow description:**

- The script `/mainscript.sh` provides only user information, interaction, and executes multiple subscripts (`/folder/subscripts.sh`).
- The script `/mainscript.sh` needs to create a new terminal window, passes the path, and the name of `subscript.sh` and executes them in the new terminal window.
- The script `/mainscript.sh` must only execute one subscript (`/folder/subscript.sh`) at the time! If a `subscript.sh` is running then the mainscript must wait until the new terminal window gets closed.
- The `subscript.sh` executes some code with root privileges.

**Questions:**

1. How can I create a new terminal window, pass the subscript, and execute it in the new terminal window?
2. How can I make sure that the script (`mainscript.sh`) only runs one subscript (`subscript.sh`) at the time?

***Example:***

mainscript.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh
    # This is the content of the mainscript.sh
    # subscript1 and subscript2 must not be executed at the same time!
    # the mainscript needs to wait when a subscript gets executed!

    echo "hello, this script runs in terminal window (((A)))"
    xterm /opt/subscript1.sh
    echo "samba - Installed"
    xterm /opt/subscript2.sh
    echo "samba - removed"
```

subscript1.sh

```
    #!bin/sh
    # This is the content of the subscript1

    echo "This script runs in a new terminal window (((B)))"
    apt-get install samba
    # instructions done .... close the terminal window (((B))) now
```

subscript2.sh

```
    #!bin/sh
    # This is the content of the subscript2

    echo "This script runs in a new terminal window (((C)))"
    apt-get remove samba
    # instructions done .... close the terminal window (((C))) now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification that you actually want a new terminal window to appear in LXDE here is a possible solution.

Debian LXDE is likely to have xterm or lxterminal installed. The example below is using lxterminal. For xterm use "xterm -e command"

Start by executing manscript.sh in its own window:

```
$ lxterminal --command=/mainscript.sh
```

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

<section that provides user information>

# Call subscripts that will run in sequence
lxterminal --command=/folder/subscripts.sh
```

When subscripts.sh finishes, the new terminal window will close and return control to mainscript.sh
You get only one subscript to run at a time by calling these in sequence.

Comment: The goal is to get two windows terminals open at the same time. The window(A) shows the executed code in the mainscript.sh. The window(B) shows the executed code in the subscripts.sh

Comment: This doesnt work. `xterm: No absolute path found for shell: /opt/subscript.sh`

Comment: Do you have lxterminal installed? Then replace by "lxterminal --command=/pathto/scripth.sh"

Comment: ...or try "xterm -e /pathto/script.sh". See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269351/xterm-no-absolute-path-found-for-shell